# How to know the time a disc takes to stop from rotating and the numbers of revolutions

Tags: rotational-dynamics

Assuming I rotate a disk, I want to know how long it takes to completely stop, and the number of revolutions it made since I removed my fingers off the disk.

Lets say a DVD I rotate with my fingers. I only know the radians per second (velocity) of the last moment I touched the disc.

Can you guys tell me where to start?

Im trying to implement this on an iPhone app. So it would be nice if you mention **equations**. It should not be exact.

Comment: Hi Jose - I'm putting the homework tag on this because it sounds like a homework-type question, but could you confirm whether it is or not? What's the context of this question?

Comment: It is not homework. Im trying to implement a simulation of what I mentioned on the question into an iOS app (iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad application).

Comment: Should the iPhone measure the rotation of a real disk or do you want to display something that kind of resembles a disk?

Comment: User is going to rotate with his fingers a object (could be a bottle of Coke, a dvd, a vynil, etc...) and I want it rotate and decelerate on a "natural" way.

Answer (score 4):

Lets say the disk originally rotated with angular frequency $\omega_0$ in Hz.

Then due to friction you will have $\omega(t)=\omega_0-d t$. Where $d$ is the deceleration in Hz/s and $t$ is the time in seconds. Note that the disk won't start turning in the opposite direction $\omega(t)>0$.

Then you get a rotation angle $\alpha(t)$:
$$\alpha(t)=\int_0^t \omega(t')\textrm{d}t'= \omega_0t - dt^2/2$$

```
(let ((omega0 50)
      (d .2)
      (start 0)
      (old-alpha 0))
  (defun start-turning (omega)
    (setf omega0 omega
          start (get-internal-real-time)))
  (defun draw ()
    (load-identity)
    (let* ((time (- (get-internal-real-time start)))
           (alpha (if (< 0 (- omega0 (* d time)))
                      (- (* omega0 time) (* d (/ 2) (expt time 2)))
                      old-alpha)))
      (rotate alpha 0 0 1)
      (setf old-alpha alpha))
    (draw-disk)))
```

Comment: I have not anything of what you mentioned before. I want an approximation or expected behaviour of it, as it will be implemented on an iPhone app as a simulation. Nothing fancy. Just the correct feeling of natural deceleration.

Comment: Then just go with linear deceleration.

Comment: I only know Initial Velocity and Final Velocity.

Comment: I give up. I don't know what you want to do with this app. However, I don't think physics will help you here. I'll just write some OpenGL drawing code that would describe how the disc would slowly come to a stop.

Comment: @whoplisp "We want it free of stalks" was the answer when the Czar sent a ships load of corn to his slavic brothers in Montenegro :=) BTW, Your solution is fine for the geometry of a viscosimeter, ie with some counter-surface at small distance. In free space the air adhering to the disk will be accelerated radially and stream away. This adds some "pump" work to the frictional loss.

Comment: @Georg I am quite sure the orginial motivation for the question was to build some user interface code that will simulate the behaviour when you touch a simulated disk on an iPhone. The question is more to find a working heuristic that turns the (touchpad) coordinate-time into something realistic. Physics doesn't help there.

Comment: The corn stalks was a comment directed to Jose, demanding simple arithmetics done for him.